# Search only rows within a color index

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I'm new to VBA (somewhat) and I was assigned the tedious task of searching over 5000 rows to highlight rows (from A to j with the colorindex=6) based on a cell value and it's taking me forever. Basically I'm trying to develop a program that searches a string under column C, if the cell is equal to the string searched, then offset to 4 row below from the active cell and for any number greater than 37 and stops when it finds a cell in a row with the index color 33. Any ideas? I started and now stuck. Any ideas will help. Thanks

```
Sub Priority()

'Declaring all worksheets in the excel file
Dim US As Worksheet
Dim Venr50 As Worksheet
Dim Priority As Worksheet
Dim CBT As String

'setting all variables declared
Set US = Worksheets("US CKS")
Set Venr = Worksheets("VENR50 US 09.24")
Set Priority = Worksheets("Priority")

CBT = Priority.Range("$C$6").Value

With US

Dim x As Long

For x = 4 To 3000

If Cells(x, "C").Value = CBT Then

ActiveCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 33
ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Select

End If
```

Comment: When you find CBT, you want to color it 33 and then offset 4 rows? Then do you want the loop to check for CBT to start at that offset row? if so you should either increment x. You will need a Next x after your End If to complete your for look as well.

Comment: I want it to find CBT, (in range C) which is already colorindex 33, and then begin searching for numbers greater than 37 four rows below it (still in range C) and highlight it colorindex 6 (from A to J), until it comes across a cell colorindex = 33. and stop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do another loop within your For loop like below:

```
Dim x As Long
Dim j as integer

For x = 4 To 3000

If Cells(x, "C").Value = CBT Then

    For j=1 to 4
        If Cells(x+j,"C").Value>37 then Cells(x+j,"C").ColorIndex = 6
        If Cells(x+j,"C").Interior.ColorIndex = 33 then exit sub
    Next j

End If

If Cells(x+j,"C").Interior.ColorIndex = 33 Then Exit Sub

Next x
```

EDIT:
 To change the color index of multiple rows you can use:

```
Range(Cells(x+j,"A"),Cells(x+j,"J")).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I was wondering why between the for and next j statement, you didn't included end if's? I thought you always had to include them.

Comment: When you If statement only has one action, you can put it on the same line following the then keyword. Otherwise, if you have multiple things to do within your if statement, you would put them on additional line and include and End If. You can still put them on separate lines with an End If to improve readability for yourself.

Comment: is there a way to highlight the color index 6 from a to J instead of that one cell?